# Beamer Presentation: Sneak in slides for each bulleted element

Tags: latex, beamer

So, I am doing a presentation using Beamer.

In my earlier presentation, I used the list elements auto unhiding one each time. : http://www.slideshare.net/scorpion032/building-pluggable-web-applications-using-django/38

using the following code:

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]                  \item
        Admin Interface                         \item
        Generic Views                           \item
        Testing Tools                           \item
        Sessions                                \item
        Authentication                          \item
        Caching                                 \item
        Internationalization                    \item
        RSS                                     \item
        CSRF protection                         \item
        File Storage                            
    \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
```

from http://github.com/becomingGuru/gids-django-ppt/blob/master/contents.tex

What I want right now, is the ability to sneak-in a few slides for each of these entries. Is there a simple direct easy way to do it?

Or should I consider using sections and displaying section titles? The problem with that approach is that, there will be way too many sections and given that I am displaying the sections on top bar, there might not be enough space for that.

Also, how do I display the contents page, with the current section highlighted for each section.

PS: Question mirrored on [TeX, LaTeX and Friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2073/beamer-presentation-sneak-in-slides-for-each-bulleted-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Mirrored from TeX.StackExchange)

Not sure of the first part, but this may help for "*how do I display the contents page, with the current section highlighted for each section*"

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \frame<handout:0>
  {
    \frametitle{Agenda}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
  }
}
```